# How to generate json2 from json1 using C#

Tags: c#, json

I have json1 which is the input to generate json2. The main logic is that I have to take only the value at the index 0 if the key is an array. pretty simple till here. Another condition is that if the Key to the Array is TYPE and the key-value pair is present inside the "DEVICE" nest then all the key-value pairs that are present in the TYPE's value should be deleted except for the the key in the 0th index.

**JSON1  (INPUT)**

```
{
  "VERSION": "VERSION 2.3.0",
  "COMPONENT": {
    "0": {
      "SUBID": 1,
      "TYPE": "TYPE 1",
      "OUTPUT TYPE": [
        "OUTPUT1",
        "OUTPUT2",
        "OUTPUT3"
      ],
      "UNIT": [
        "UNIT1",
        "UNIT2",
        "UNIT3"
      ],
      "DEVICE": {
        "SUBID": 2,
        "TYPE": [
          "DEVICE TYPE 1",
          "DEVICE TYPE 2",
          "DEVICE TYPE 3"
        ],
        "DEVICE TYPE 1": {
          "SUBID": 3,
          "TYPE": [
            "TYPE A",
            "TYPE B",
            "TYPE C",
            "TYPE D"
          ],
          "COLD": [
            "TRUE",
            "FALSE"
          ],
          "EXTERNAL": [
            "ON",
            "OFF"
          ]
        },
        "DEVICE TYPE 2": {
          "SUBID": 4,
          "TYPE": [
            "TYPE X",
            "TYPE Y",
            "TYPE Z"
          ],
          "VALUE": 0.0,
          "CO-EFFS": 0.0
        },
        "DEVICE TYPE 3": {
          "SUBID": 5,
          "EXTRACTION": [
            "1",
            "2"
          ],
          "EXTRACTION VALUE": 1.0,
          "APPROXIMATION": [
            "OFF",
            "ON"
          ]
        }
      },
      "CALIBRATION OFFSET AND GAIN": [
        "DISABLE",
        "ENABLE"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**JSON2  (EXPECTED OUTPUT)**

```
{
  "VERSION": "VERSION 2.3.0",
  "COMPONENT": {
    "0": {
      "SUBID": 1,
      "TYPE": "TYPE 1",
      "OUTPUT TYPE": "OUTPUT1",
      "UNIT": "UNIT1",
      "DEVICE": {
        "SUBID": 2,
        "TYPE": "DEVICE TYPE 1",
        "DEVICE TYPE 1": {
          "SUBID": 3,
          "TYPE": "TYPE A",
          "COLD": "TRUE",
          "EXTERNAL": "ON"
        }
      },
      "CALIBRATION OFFSET AND GAIN": "DISABLE"
    }
  }
}
```

**CURRENT OUTPUT**

```
{
  "VERSION": "VERSION 2.3.0",
  "COMPONENT": {
    "0": {
      "SUBID": 1,
      "TYPE": "TYPE 1",
      "OUTPUT TYPE": "OUTPUT1",
      "UNIT": "UNIT1",
      "DEVICE": {
        "SUBID": 2,
        "TYPE": "DEVICE TYPE 1",
        "DEVICE TYPE 1": {
          "SUBID": 3,
          "TYPE": "TYPE A",
          "COLD": "TRUE",
          "EXTERNAL": "ON"
        },
        "DEVICE TYPE 2": {
          "SUBID": 4,
          "TYPE": "TYPE X",
          "VALUE": 0.0,
          "CO-EFFS": 0.0
        },
        "DEVICE TYPE 3": {
          "SUBID": 5,
          "EXTRACTION": "1",
          "EXTRACTION VALUE": 1.0,
          "APPROXIMATION": "OFF"
        }
      },
      "CALIBRATION OFFSET AND GAIN": "DISABLE"
    }
  }
}
```

in the CURRENT OUTPUT, there are excess keys(DEVICE TYPE 2 and DEVICE TYPE 3) these should be removed because the values for the key inside the device nest is DEVICE TYPE 1.

this is the code I have tried.

**MAIN function**

```
        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
             // change the file path 
            //var root = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText("C:/Users/path_to_input_json/input.json"));
            var root = JObject.Parse(@"{ ""VERSION"":""VERSION 2.3.0"",""COMPONENT"":{ ""0"":{ ""SUBID"":1,""TYPE"":""TYPE 1"",""OUTPUT TYPE"":[""OUTPUT1"",""OUTPUT2"",""OUTPUT3""],""UNIT"":[""UNIT1"",""UNIT2"",""UNIT3""],""DEVICE"":{""SUBID"":2,""TYPE"":[""DEVICE TYPE 1"",""DEVICE TYPE 2"",""DEVICE TYPE 3""],""DEVICE TYPE 1"":{""SUBID"":3,""TYPE"":[""TYPE A"",""TYPE B"",""TYPE C"",""TYPE D""],""COLD"":[""TRUE"",""FALSE""],""EXTERNAL"":[""ON"",""OFF""]
    },""DEVICE TYPE 2"":{""SUBID"":4,""TYPE"":[""TYPE X"",""TYPE Y"",""TYPE Z""],""VALUE"":0,""CO-EFFS"":0},""DEVICE TYPE 3"":{""SUBID"":5,""EXTRACTION"":[""1"",""2""],""EXTRACTION VALUE"":1,""APPROXIMATION"":[""OFF"",""ON""]}},""CALIBRATION OFFSET AND GAIN"":[""DISABLE"",""ENABLE""]}}}");
            var descendants = root.DescendantsAndSelf().ToList();
            List<string> sensor_subtype_list = new List<string>();
            foreach (var d in descendants)
            {
                var jProp = d as JProperty;
                if (jProp != null)
                {
                    if (jProp?.Value is JArray array)
                    {
                        if (jProp.Name == "TYPE")
                        {
                            var value = jProp.Value as JArray;
                            sensor_subtype_list = value.ToObject<List<string>>();
                            jProp.Value = jProp.Value[0];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (sensor_subtype_list.Count != 0)
                            {
                                if (sensor_subtype_list.Contains(jProp.Name) && jProp.Name != sensor_subtype_list[0])
                                {
                                    jProp.Remove();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    jProp.Value = jProp.Value[0];
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                jProp.Value = jProp.Value[0];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (sensor_subtype_list.Count != 0)
                        {
                            if (sensor_subtype_list.Contains(jProp.Name) && jProp.Name != sensor_subtype_list[0])
                            {
                                jProp.Remove();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(root.ToString());
        }
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Why are you reading the JSON, parsing it, converting it back to a string, and then parsing it again? (I'd change `GetJson` to a return a `JObject`, and I'd use `File.ReadAllText` to make the code rather simpler...) I'd also strongly recommend starting to follow .NET naming conventions for variables. Finally, there's no need for `@$` in the string literal you're using in `GetJson`, nor any need for doubling the *forward*-slashes...

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for the input ill make sure to follow your suggestions

Comment: Also, rather than taking the name of the type of a value, I'd use the `is` operator: `if (jprop?.Value is JArray array) { ... }`. (And there's no need to call `ToString()` on existing string properties such as `jProp.Name`.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I have edited the question to incorporate your suggestion. 